# What will be the value of uninitialized variable?

Tags: c, initialization, garbage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is uninitialized data behavior well specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824488/is-uninitialized-data-behavior-well-specified)

I tried the following code

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
int i; \
printf('%d',i);
}
```

The result gave garbage value in VC++, while same in tc was zero.
What will be the correct value?
Will an uninitialized variable by default have value of zero? or it will contain garbage value?

Next is on the same

```
#include<stdio.h> 
void main()
{
int i,j,num;
j=(num>0?0:num*num);
printf("\n%d",j);
}
```

What will be the output of the code above?

Comment: It's undefined. That's why it's garbage. In C, you gotta initialize things yourself.

Comment: Which language? C or C? Oh wait...

Comment: The output your code gave me: http://i48.servimg.com/u/f48/11/68/36/17/nasal_10.png  :-O

Comment: Voting to reopen. The linked duplicate is a C++ question, and C and C++ are different languages which have different rules surrounding uninitialized variables.

Comment: The link to Stroustrup's FAQ has changed to http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main.

Comment: `main()` returns `int` and takes the arguments `int argc` and `char **argv`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Technically, the value of an uninitialized  non static local variable is **Indeterminate**<sup>[Ref 1]</sup>.
In short it can be anything. Accessing such a uninitialized variable leads to an **Undefined Behavior**.<sup>[Ref 2]</sup>

<sup>[Ref 1]</sup>
**C99 section 6.7.8 Initialization:**

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

<sup>[Ref 2]</sup>

**C99 section 3.18 Undeﬁned behavior:**

> **behavior, upon use of** a nonportable or erroneous program construct, of erroneous data, or of **indeterminately valued objects**, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements.

Note: Emphasis mine.

Comment: OP is asking about C (C89?), not C++03.

Comment: @keelerjr12: It was retagged later.Modified for C99.

Comment: Why do you answer to such an obvious dupe? I thought better of you.

Comment: @sbi: I have always known the first two statements of my answer.I didn't really know exactly which part of the C standard explicitly says them(*I know precisely where C++ standard states so*).I was keen on finding the detail for C standard(*Yes,I am not well versed in C*).If you see my answer edits i took a lot of time to find the exact details where the C standard states this.I edited to detail after this Q was closed.It was more of learning a experience myself rather than just providing an answer.And I do admit I am selfish enough to want to learn things rather than just give answers.

Comment: @Als: Why do you answer to such an obvious dupe? I thought better of you.

Comment: This is most inaccurate and the reference 2 is irrelevant - you aren't citing the part of the standard that labels this UB. Because there isn't even any obvious source in the standard saying so. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40674888/584518

Answer (score 4):

Accessing an unitialized variable is undefined behavior in both C and C++, so reading any value is possible.

It is also possible that your program crashes: once you get into undefined behavior territory, all bets are off<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> I have never seen a program crashing over accessing an uninitalized variable, unless it's a pointer.

Comment: For implementations that include trap representations, reading an uninitialized object of any type other than unsigned char (including int) may trigger a trap.

Comment: Citation needed. This is mostly incorrect. Systems with trap representations are mostly fictional and need not be taken in account for the vast majority of programs out there. In many cases, accessing an uninitialized variable does _not_ invoke UB. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior

Answer (score 2):

It's indeterminate.  The compiler can do what it wants.

Comment: To be pedantic; its value is indeterminate; using it results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The value is indeterminate; using the variable before initialization results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

It's *undefined*. It might be different between different compilers, different operating systems, different runs of the program, anything. It might not even be a particular value: the compiler is allowed to do whatever it likes to this code, because the effect isn't defined. It might choose to optimize away your whole program. It might even choose to replace your program with one that installers a keylogger and steals all of your online banking login details.

If you want to know the value, the only way is to set it.

Answer (score -1):

As others have noted, the value *can* be anything.

This sometimes leads to hard-to-find bugs, e.g. because you *happen* to get one value in a debug build and get a different value in a release build, or the initial value that you get depends on previous program execution.

Lesson: ALWAYS initialize variables.  There's a reason that C# defines values for fields and requires initialization for local variables.