# Why are the 12 bits of uninitialized int variable always 0xff0?

Tags: c, gcc

When I try to explain some simple code to my friends,something strange happens:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int x;
    printf("%x\n",x);
}
```

I have tryed millions of times ,and the last 12 bits of x always turns out to be 0xff0.
I've disass the code,but still can't figure out what's going on here

My operating system is ubuntu10.10 ,compiler is gcc4.7.2

Comment: Is it just even, or is it a multiple of 4 or 8?

Comment: Why is this question being closed? It's a valid programming question with a simple answer?

Comment: @ChrisW I found it's not just even, the last 3 bits always turns out to be 0xff0.I've edited my question. thank you!

Comment: @PreetSangha It's unclear, because 0xff0 is 12 bits, not 3. It's the very definition of “too localized”. It duplicates a number of easy-to-find SO questions such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233602/what-will-be-the-value-of-uninitialized-variable

Comment: 0xFF0 is only a byte and a half.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, if the value always matches 0xFF0 then the "lower 12 bits" are that value, not the lower 3.

As for why this happens, you're reading a variable that you haven't initialized. That's undefined behavior, and anything could have happened when you tried to do this, from a crash to a pizza getting delivered.

But what *actually* happens is this: the location that x references has some data that it held previously. Chances are that on your setup, that variable happens to contain data whose lower twelve bits are 0xFF0; in which case it's most likely data associated a previous system call, during processing work done by the system before your `main` is called.

To make a long story short: **initialize your variables before using them and don't ask why the uninitialized ones have the value they do.**

Answer (score 6):

Reading an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior. So you are guaranteed nothing.

This includes always being zero, always being even, always being different, and reformatting your hard drive.

Comment: An uninitialized variable once ran off with my girlfriend. True story.

Comment: @JasonD - With good reason, I'm sure.

Answer (score 2):

The value is always the same because your program is *deterministic*.

The value of an uninitialized variable is officially "undefined", but in a program that always goes through the exact same steps it may well be *predictable*. In this case it turns out that whatever used that register or stack slot before main needed the value you see.

The only time a program would not be deterministic is if it interacts with something else that is non-deterministic (such as a user, or a changeable file, or the network). A threaded program may be non-deterministic without any external stimuli, however.

Answer (score 0):

> I found it's not just even, the last 3 bits always turns out to be

Maybe the previous thing that was stored in that location on the stack is the value of a pointer to heap-allocated memory, or something like that (heap-allocated blocks are often rounded to a boundary, e.g. an 8-byte boundary).