# Why gcc didn't print 0 consistenly after a declaration int

Tags: c, gcc, declaration

With the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int num;
    printf("%d\n", num);

    int* num2;
    printf("%p\n", &num2);

    return 0;
}
```

I got result like:

[image]

From [Memory allocation for global and local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value),
I know the global variable `num` is initialized to `0` implicitly,
even it is not initialized by me.

Now I am just trying something randomly, so I change the code to

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int num;
    printf("%d\n", num);

    int* num2;
    printf("%p\n", num2);

    return 0;
}
```

and now I get

[image]

**Question:** I don't know WHY the value of `num` is no longer `0`.

In my opinion, what I am doing with the variable `num2` and its value HAS
NOTHING TO DO WITH the variable `num`.

I am not only interested why, but also want to hear your opinions
about this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

```
int num;
printf("%d\n", num);

int* num2;
printf("%p\n", num2);
```

In both cases above you are reading values of uninitialized variables (in one case this variable is simple integer, in other case pointer - but like I said in both cases their values are not initialized).

Local variables are not initialized by default.

Reading values of uninitialized variables is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This was fine

```
int* num2;
printf("%p\n", &num2);
```

because `&num` is address of `num` pointer - it has defined value.
Though more correct is to use:

```
   printf("%p\n", (void*) &num2);
```

In other cases too where you use `%p`.

Comment: `Reading values of uninitialized variables is undefined behavior.` No; only if they can contain trap-representations, such as floats. You might get undefined *results*, though.

Comment: @wildplasser hm I think on SO reading values of uninitialized variables is commonly referred as UB: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/364/undefined-behavior/2576/reading-an-uninitialized-object-that-is-not-backed-by-memory#t=201608101257444574981

Comment: @wildplasser where is dereference mentioned?

Comment: In the "article" you linked to. (it is even the title)

Comment: @wildplasser check it once again

Comment: I see. It *could* be a wrong interpretation of The Standard, though. (the docs are only a few days old)

Comment: @wildplasser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233602/what-will-be-the-value-of-uninitialized-variable

Comment: @wildplasser, if an object with automatic storage duration has no initializer then its initial value is indeterminate.  The standard specifies that one of the ways a program has undefined behavior is if "The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate."  (C2011, J.2)  The analysis doesn't reach the question of whether the value is a trap representation.

Comment: It must have been changed since C99. I stand corrected. The trap-reprentation was the rationale in the older standard, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

`local` variables without `static` keyword have `automatic` storage duration.`num` is one such variable.

And reading a value of a varibale with `automatic` storage **before** assigning any value to it can result in anything. So you cannot expect some determinate output.

And yes, as your code is, what you are doing with the variable `num2` and its value HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH the variable `num`. But `num2` and `num` can be relaed if you do `num2 = &num;`, after which what you you assign to `*num2` will impact the value of `num`.