# Concatenating strings in C: string buffer is not getting cleared after function call

Tags: c, initialization, c-strings, uninitialized-constant

I am trying to concat two strings in the function `foo()`. I expect the content of `string` to be `abc` after both the first and second calls to `foo()`. The output which I get after the first call is `abc` but the second call prints `abcabc` (the third call prints `abcabcabc` and so on). The string buffer is not getting cleared. It will be helpful if someone could share how it works internally - how the memory is assigned to the string and why the string buffer is not cleared between subsequent calls of the function.

Here is the code I used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int foo(){
    unsigned char string[100];
    unsigned char text[10] = "abc";
    strcat(string, text);
    printf("%s\n", string);
}

int main(){
    foo();
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no C runtime. Memory is not cleared between function calls. Someone has to do it. In your case you might want `memset(string, 0, strlen(text))` at the end of the function. That being said you probably also want to be using `strcpy` instead of `strcat`. The way you have it now `string` is never initialized so `strcat`'s length finding could you to read memory you don't have permissions to.

Comment: looking at your code, it seems pretty obvious that the result which you got, was what the function was doing, as you've not initialised the `string`: invokes [Undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/8484779)

Comment: The documentation for [`strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) is self-explanatory. It requires the first argument be (a) a null-terminated string (b) with buffer space of sufficient capacity to house the current string, the addendum string, *and* a terminating nullchar. Your code does not deliver on the first of those requirements, and therefore you invoke *undefined behavior*. Read and understand how the library functions you're using work.

Comment: "why the string buffer is not cleared between subsequent calls of the function": Because there is nothing in the language that ever claimed that it would be cleared. If you thought there was, I'm afraid you're misled. Uninitialized local variables have *indeterminate* contents, and that includes the possibility of seeing leftover data from previous calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the `string` variable. This is the reason for all your problems. Trying to access the value of an uninitialized variable causes [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Refer to [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int foo(){
    unsigned char string[100] = "";
    unsigned char text[10] = "abc";
    strcat(string, text);
    printf("%s\n", string);
}

int main(){
    foo();
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`string` hasn't been initialized so doesn't contain a valid string. As a result when `strcat` reads it to find the null terminator it [invokes undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11233602/995714). You must initialize it before using

```
unsigned char string[100] = { 0 };
```