# What does *new int mean?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Can someone help me with this question?

The memory allocated on line (*) below is not deleted.

```
void f() {
    int z = *new int; // (*)
    //...
}
```

Without changing the code on line (*), is there any way to avoid leaking memory? If so, how? If not, why not?

What I don't understand is, what does `*new int` mean? Specifically, what does adding the `*` beside new mean?

Also, what if instead of int z, we have `int &z`?

Comment: It means somebody is doing something very stupid. If you used `int &z` then you could do `delete &z` but that is very non-idiomatic code and will raise lots of eyebrows.

Comment: Is this an interview question?

Comment: @Simple: can be a workaround to avoid pointer dereferences in the body of the function.

Comment: `*new` is the *memory leak operator*. Don't use it.

Comment: @Werner. It is an old exam question

Comment: I guessed so. So you give us the exam question, don't show any effort to answer it and ask us for the answer!?

Answer (score 6):

**That** line *is* the memory leak.  It also makes no sense what so ever allocating an `int` int on heap and derefencing it (with `*`) before saving it's handle (address returned by `new`).  So the only posible way to avoid the leak is:

```
return;
// your silly * line here
```

Answer (score 6):

> Without changing the code on line (*), is there any way to avoid leaking memory?

In real life, you would absolutely change that line - it's insane.

Assuming this is an intellectual exercise, then possibilities are:

- Add `return;` before it, so the `new` never happens;
- Override `::operator new` to return a pointer that you can access by other means, such as a global variable.

> What I don't understand is, what does `*new int` mean?

`new int` dynamically allocates an object of type `int`, and gives a pointer to that. `*` dereferences that pointer so that the object can be copied to initialise `z`. The pointer is not stored anywhere, so there is no way to access or delete the dynamic object afterwards.

Also, the initialisation of `z` from the value of an uninitialised object gives undefined behaviour.

> Also, what if instead of `int z`, we have `int &z`?

`z` would be a reference to, rather than a copy of, the dynamic object. It would then be possible to fix the leak with `delete &z`. That would be an unidiomatic, confusing thing to do; don't do it in real code.

In general, avoid dynamic allocation and, when it is necessary, manage dynamic resources with RAII types, like containers and smart pointers. Raw pointers are error-prone, expecially when exceptions are thrown; anything else is a recipe for insanity.

Answer (score 3):

That to understand this statement

```
int z = *new int; // (*)
```

it will be useful to split it logically.

At first there is called operator

```
new int
```

Take into account that the memory allocated by this call will not be initialized.

The result of the execution of the statement is some temporary pointer to int that is `int *`
Let;s name it as `p`.

In the next step this temporary pointer is dereferenced

```
*p
```

and this expression returns some garbage that the allocated memory has.

And this garbage are assigned to variable `z`.

So the code has no any sense.

At least it would be better to write something as

```
int z = *new int( 10 );
```

or

```
int z = *new int();
```

or

```
int z = *new int {};
```

that to initialize variavle `z`

Nevertheless in any case there will be memory leak.

The only method that I see to escape the memory leak is to write

```
int z = *std::unique_ptr<int>( new int() );
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to not leak memory with that code, since the pointer returned by `new` is lost.

`*new int` means "allocate memory for an `int`, resulting in a pointer to that memory, then dereference the pointer, yielding the (uninitialized) `int` itself". I think this is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Deduplicator By not doing the troublesome thing, yes, sure ... I would argue that to be equivalent with "there's no way to leak memory with that code", though. I'll clarify.

Comment: If it had been an uninitialized automatic variable nobody ever took the address of, or the implementation-defined representation of `int` allows trap representations, it could be UB. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839466/any-guarantees-for-uninitialised-variables