# What does (*new) mean In c++?

Tags: c++, qt

I am following an online course on Qt framework, and I found code like this:

```
StartUp::StartUp(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent),
    m_engine(*new QQmlApplicationEngine()),
    m_mainViewMgr(*new MainViewMgr)

{
 //some code
}
```

My question is what does `(*new )` mean?

I know that the `new` operator returns a pointer to dynamically allocated memory.
if `(*new )` means dereferencing the returned pointer, wouldn't this cause memory leak?

Comment: It's just dereferencing the returned pointer.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434625/what-does-new-int-mean?rq=1

Comment: Note that if `m_engine` and `m_mainViewMgr` take reference as parameter (or are themselves references), there is no direct memory leak here even though this is quite disturbing to look at..., plus this is Qt code so Qt may manage the memory internally.

Comment: If we assume that `m_engine` is a reference, would `delete &m_engine;` have well defined behavior?

Comment: Qt does a lot of memory management itself, by deleting objects derived from QObject. That should be the case with `m_engine`, though I couldn't say what `m_mainViewMgr`.

Comment: @Holt would A non-const reference cause an undefined behaviour (since the reference have a longer lifetime than the temporary object) ?

Comment: I've voted to reopen because this is specifically tagged with Qt which does memory management, therefore not a duplicate.

Comment: @acraig5075 Qt or not, the meaning of `*new` is the same, which is what is being asked.

Comment: @nefas `*new QQmlApplicationEngine()` is not a "variable" with automatic storage duration, so there is no lifetime extension induced by a const reference, but you are simply (probably) storing a reference to a heap allocated object, that you can delete using e.g. `delete &m_engine;`. Can't be sure without more information about `m_engine` and `m_mainViewMgr`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The context is quite different - In the duplicate, there is a clear memory leak, here it's unclear. The first answer of the duplicate is basically *"This is a memory leak."*, which (probably) does not apply here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: The whoever wrote that "online course" decided to do 95% of the job :)

Presumably, the `StartUp` class is declared as follows:

```
class StartUp : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QQmlApplicationEngine & m_engine;
  MainViewMgr & m_mainViewMgr;
public:
  StartUp(QObject * parent = {});
};
```

Since both the `QQmlApplicationEngine` and `MainViewMgr` are supposed to last as long as the `StartUp` object is alive, keeping them via reference might make some sense. Alas, unless parents are set for both objects, the objects will leak, so at the very minimum the correct constructor should look as follows:

```
StartUp::StartUp(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent),
    m_engine(*new QQmlApplicationEngine(this)),
    m_mainViewMgr(*new MainViewMgr(this))
{}
```

At this point you should ask yourself: why not just hold the objects by value? There's no point to holding them via reference and explicitly creating them on the heap. Thus:

```
class StartUp : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QQmlApplicationEngine m_engine{this};
  MainViewMgr m_mainViewMgr{this};
public:
  StartUp(QObject * parent = {}) : QObject(parent) {}
};
```

Both objects are still created with a parent in case `StartUp` was moved to another thread - they will then follow it safely. If `StartUp` is only meant to be used in the main thread, the member objects can be parentless:

```
class StartUp : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QQmlApplicationEngine m_engine;
  MainViewMgr m_mainViewMgr;
public:
  StartUp(QObject * parent = {}) : QObject(parent) {}
};
```