# An uninitialized variable/pointer becomes a definition or a declaration?

Tags: c, declaration, definition

Suppose I have the following program:

```
int main(void)
{
int i; //Line 1
i=5;  //Line 2

int *j; //line 3
j=&i; //line 4
}
```

If I try to print i after line 1 in Visual Studio, it gives me a compile time error saying unitialized variable i used. Does this mean that no storage was allocated to i and line 1 is only a declaration? I understand line 2 is a definition.

Also, what about line 3 and line 4? Are they declarations or definitions?

Comment: storage is allocated but value not assigned.

Comment: Storage is allocated but value not assigned is declaration or definition?

Comment: In gcc, it prints garbage values. Does not throw compile time error

Comment: Have a look at [difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration).

Comment: @user2684198 in defination. Also printing it leads [Undefined Behavior.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824488/is-uninitialized-data-behavior-well-specified)

Comment: Line 2 is an assignment, not a definition.  Line 1 is a definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line 1 and Line 3 are definitions, It's also legal to say they are declarations because all definitions are declarations.

The error is because using uninitialized variables is undefined behavior, not because their storage are not allocated.

Line 2 and Line 4 are assignment statements. You seem to be confused with initalization and assignment.

```
int n = 42; //definition with initalization
int m;      //definition, but uninitiazlied
n = 10;     //assignment
m = 10;     //assignment
```